# squared euclidian distance as a heuristic for A*-algorithm

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I've read that for the A*-algorithm the squared euclidian distance is not a good heuristic, because it might lead to wrong shortest paths. I further found two counterexamples, but I don't understand how to interpret them and how I get to the values of h and f.

The counterexamples are this:

[image: examples]

It would be great, if anyone could explain how to get to such a counterexample and how to interpret it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain what do the numbers in the boxes exactly mean?

Comment: "the squared euclidian distance is not a good heuristic", To what problem are you applying $A^*$? What is written here is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Squared euclidean distance is not metric.  Consider a triangle of side lengths $1$, $1$, and $\frac 3 2$ where you wish to travel the shortest distance from one end of the long edge to the other.

The squared distances give $1^2 + 1^2 < \left(\frac 3 2\right)^2$, which is both not metric and results in incorrectly choosing to go along the 2 shorter edges of the triangle rather than just the one longer edge.